# Anybody know if OrcTableSource supports S3 file system?

Tags: apache-flink

I'm running into some troubles with using OrcTableSource to fetch Orc file from cloud Object storage(IBM COS), the code fragment is provided below:

```
OrcTableSource soORCTableSource = OrcTableSource.builder() // path to ORC
    .path("s3://orders/so.orc") // s3://orders/so.csv
    // schema of ORC files
    .forOrcSchema(OrderHeaderORCSchema)
    .withConfiguration(orcconfig)
    .build();
```

seems this path is incorrect but anyone can help out? appreciate a lot!

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /so.orc does not exist
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:611)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:824)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:428)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.(ChecksumFileSystem.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:346)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:768)    at
>   org.apache.orc.impl.ReaderImpl.extractFileTail(ReaderImpl.java:528)
>     at org.apache.orc.impl.ReaderImpl.(ReaderImpl.java:370)   at
>   org.apache.orc.OrcFile.createReader(OrcFile.java:342)     at
>   org.apache.flink.orc.OrcRowInputFormat.open(OrcRowInputFormat.java:225)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.orc.OrcRowInputFormat.open(OrcRowInputFormat.java:63)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSourceTask.invoke(DataSourceTask.java:170)
>     at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:711)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

By the way, I've already set up flink-s3-fs-presto-1.6.2 and had following code running correctly. The question is limited to OrcTableSource only.

```
DataSet<Tuple5<String, String, String, String, String>> orderinfoSet =
    env.readCsvFile("s3://orders/so.csv")
        .types(String.class, String.class, String.class
                ,String.class, String.class);
```

Comment: More information?

Comment: If I use path: s3:///bucket/object instead of s3://bucket/object in OrcTableSource Builder, then I'm seeing following exception. Caused by: org.apache.flink.fs.s3presto.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The specified bucket does not exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchBucket; Request ID: ed4025ca-91a8-4795-8068-948fbfc3508f), S3 Extended Request ID: null
 at org.apache.flink.fs.s3presto.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1587)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Flink's `OrcRowInputFormat` uses two different file systems: One for generating the input splits and one for reading the actual input splits. For the former, it uses Flink's `FileSystem` abstraction and for the latter it uses Hadoop's `FileSystem`. Therefore, you need to configure Hadoop's configuration `core-site.xml` to contain the following snippet

```
<property>
  <name>fs.s3.impl</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
</property>
```

See [this link](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/deployment/aws.html#hadoop-provided-s3-file-systems---manual-setup) for more information about setting up S3 for Hadoop.

This is a limitation of Flink's `OrcRowInputFormat` and should be fixed. I've created [the corresponding issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-10989).

Comment: Thanks Till for your reply. However, I'm not running my Flink with a dedicated Hadoop env, but just use S3 wrapper with shaded Hadoop package. so the additional manual configuration is not applicable for this case.  Any other way to walk around? or do you have a target date to fix OrcRowInputFormat in Flink?

Comment: Then I guess it would be good to add `core-site.xml` to your class path as well as the S3 Hadoop FS implementation (or put the implementation in `lib` of Flink's Home directory)